# How to add Auto increment Field, Which isn't a Primary Key in Django Models

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I want to add a field id in my Django Model. The primary key is the email id. I want the id field to be AUTO_INCERMENT. 
we can use models following 
`AutoField(primary_key=True)` but this makes id the primary key to the id, which isn't the desired case. it returns the following error.

```
django.db.utils.Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key [SQLCode: 1075], [SQLState: 42000]
```

below code for model

```
class USER(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
```

when I am making `primary_key=False` it will return same error

```
django.db.utils.Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key [SQLCode: 1075], [SQLState: 42000]
```

Comment: Django does not support non-primary key AutoFields and you will probably end up with migration issues if you work around that. Making `id` the primary key is the most viable solution.

Comment: Thanks but, this isn't the desired use case. definitely I will think about some other approach.

Comment: Unfortunately Django does not support your desired database schema. If you want an `AutoField` column it **has to be** your primary key.

Comment: Thank You @Selcuk . I am going with this approach.